# Got an email: Please provide terms of service and privacy statements for each of your apps registered with Microsoft by May 21, 2018

Tags: notifications, azure-active-directory

We have received this email.

> Please provide terms of service and privacy statements for each of your apps registered with Microsoft by May 21, 2018
>
> You’re receiving this email because our records indicate you have one or more apps registered in the Azure portal or the Application Registration Portal.
>   As part of our GDPR efforts, to give users increased privacy control and to help users assess credibility of apps they use, we are making some changes to the consent screen that users see when they are granting permissions to apps registered with Microsoft.
>
> Recommended action
>   We recommend you provide terms of service and a privacy statement for each of your apps by May 21, 2018 to avoid a warning to users on the consent screen.
>
> If you registered your app in the Azure portal:
>   1.    Sign in to the Azure portal.
>   2.    Navigate to the App registrations blade, and select your app.
>   3.    Click Properties, and then enter the terms of service URL and privacy statement URL.
>   4.    Save your changes.
>
> If you registered your application in the Application Registration Portal or Dev Center:
>   1.    Sign in to the Application Registration Portal.
>   2.    Select your app, and then scroll to the Profile section.
>   3.    Enter the terms of service URL and privacy statement URL, and then save your changes.
>
> More information
>   If you have questions, please reach out to us on StackOverflow.

Do you have examples for "TermsOfService URL and Privacy statement URL?

Comment: Do you mean example content to put at those URLs? There are a number of results if you search the web for 'example GDPR privacy policy' etc. I think the specifics of GDPR are considered off-topic here (e.g. [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365942/where-to-process-gdpr-questions)).

Comment: Correct, the content which I can put under "TermsOfService and Privacy statement.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and as such is off topic here. They should not have told you to reach out on Stack Overflow for this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.